# How to extract the indexes values from a list and replace them in another specific data frame R?

Tags: r, dataframe

Data frame **X** contains information from a especific population, say:

```
  EF ORG_PRES TYPE_CONT
 R01  FEDERAL      BASE
 AX1  OUTCOME      CLUE
 R02  FEDERAL      OPT1
```

And I have a three lists our vectors that works for me like catalogs dataframes like this:

list1

```
 Id_EF  EF
    35 R01
    36 AX1
    37 R02
```

list2

```
 Id_TYPE_CONT TYPE_CONT
          101      OPT1
          201      BASE
          301      CLUE
```

list3

```
 Id_ORG_PRES ORG_PRES
        0034  FEDERAL
        0035  OUTCOME
```

What I need is to extract the values from data frame **X** and replace them for their respective indexes values from the lists. The output I expect is a data frame that looks like this one:

```
 EF ORG_PRES TYPE_CONT
 35     0034       201
 36     0035       301
 37     0034       101
```

It does not have to be the same **X** data frame.

I do not want to make a loop function but data frame **X** is large, and the variables are factors with high number of leves.

Comment: Why not just use `match` to re-populate your columns? Just 3 match calls would do it inside a data.frame call.

Comment: @42 - do show the OP your proposed solution as it seems obvious to you.

Comment: @Parfait I am more likely to answer questions when reproducible datasets are offered using R code; dput output preferred or text that I don't need to edit and work around glitches caused by superfluous delimiters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP -- in future, please make it easy for us to copy-paste your sample data, as noted in the comments above.

One approach to your problem is to use a combination of `Reduce` and `merge`:

```
out <- Reduce(function(x, y) {
  merge(x, y, all.x = TRUE)
}, list(list1, X, list2, list3))[, paste0("Id_", names(X))]
out
#   Id_EF Id_ORG_PRES Id_TYPE_CONT
# 1    35        0034          201
# 2    37        0034          101
# 3    36        0035          301
```